# c++ primer Binary Search by iterator

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, search, iterator

The question is in the comment!

**Code:**

```
auto beg = text.begin(), end = text.end();  
auto mid = text.begin() + (end - beg) / 2;

while(mid != end && *mid != key)   
{

    if (key < *mid)
        end = mid;   //why not end = mid - 1??
    else
        beg = mid + 1;
    mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
}
```

This question have stuck me for a long time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much shorter answer:

The invariant is that `end` is always "one past the end" of the interval to search.

Since the interval you want to search is `beg .. mid-1`, `mid` is the "one past the end" iterator.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say the numbers that you want to search in are in an array and they are:

```
11  26  33  68  87 99
```

At the start of the loop, `start` points to `11` and `end` points to 1 number past `99` and `mid` points to `33`. In each iteration of the loop `end` points to 1 number past the numbers that will be used in the lookup.

Let's say you are searching for `26`. If you use

```
end = mid - 1
```

`end` will point to `26` in the second iteration and `26` will never be found.

If you use

```
end = mid
```

`end` will point to `33` in the second iteration and `26` will eventually be found.

Answer (score 0):

Let's run your code in a piece of paper and see what happens with both approaches; I will use this notation: `3.idx` as the iterator that points to the element 3 from the input.

```
auto beg = text.begin(), end = text.end();  
auto mid = text.begin() + (end - beg) / 2;

while(mid != end && *mid != key)   
{

    if (key < *mid)
        end = mid;   //why not end = mid - 1??
    else
        beg = mid + 1;
    mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
}
```

Let's run it:

```
Input: `12345`.
Key:   `-10`.

beg = 1
end = 5
mid = 3

3.idx != 5.idx and 3 not -10
if(-10 < 3)
  end.idx = 3.idx
mid.idx = 1.idx + 1 = 2

Now we check only "123":

2.idx != 3.idx and 2 not -10
if(-10 < 2)
  end.idx = 2.idx
mid.idx = 1.idx + 0 = 1

Now we check only "12":

1.idx != 2.idx and 1 not -10
if(-10 < 1)
  end.idx = 1.idx
mid.idx = 1.idx + 0 = 1

Now we check only "1":

1.idx == 1.idx stop.
```

Now with:

```
auto beg = text.begin(), end = text.end();  
auto mid = text.begin() + (end - beg) / 2;

while(mid != end && *mid != key)   
{

    if (key < *mid)
        end = mid - 1  // Only change
    else
        beg = mid + 1;
    mid = beg + (end - beg) / 2;
}
```

we would get:

```
Input: `12345`.
Key:   `-10`.

beg = 1
end = 5
mid = 3

3.idx != 5.idx and 3 not -10
if(-10 < 3)
  end.idx = 3.idx - 1 = 2.idx
mid.idx = 1.idx + 0 = 1

Now we check only "12":

1.idx != 2.idx and 1 not -10
```

STOP, did you see what happened?

We didn't check if 2 was actually the `key`, but we should do so... ;)

Comment: thanks for your passion!To be honest,I have already done what you advised so I want to know what causes it or what happens inside.So molbdnilo is the best answer for me.but thank you again :)

Comment: @HIPPOLD really happy you find your perfect answer! A tip for the next questions of yours: report what you have done; had I knew I would have posted a different answer! ;)